# Migrating production server to dev (only the sql data) site errors

Tags: magento2.3

Im struggling to get a dev\backup of our production site to a local server as a backup. I cant rsync because of access limitations to the production server but I have backed up the mysql data and imported it to the new site. I have run the update query to change the url's but I cant for the life of my get the site or admin panel to work. The error indicates a theme which was used in the production which Im not using in de (although Im sure Ive reset this within the mysql tables). The error is

[2020-08-25 08:42:46] main.CRITICAL: Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed {"report_id":"7985f88bee792eea8898ef7346de1bf76131b11475ed07909169a673bd960486","exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed at /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Design/Fallback/Rule/Simple.php:61)"} []

Any ideas how to sort this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this by removing the theme within mysql and then re indexing the cache, var & session folders.

The layout of the site is a bit out but its working.